# Solidity Syntax error - SENT

Tags: solidity

I'm learning Solidity from official documentation and stack on an exercise where I create simple coin:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20; // should actually be 0.4.21

   contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // This is the constructor whose code is
    // run only when the contract is created.
    function Coin() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

When i try to compile i got a syntax error on the last line:
   **emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);**

I tried to compile it in Remix and VS Code but got the same error message.

Can somebody help me pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `emit` keyword was added in Solidity 0.4.21. Prior to that version, you emit events by using just the event name.

`Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);`

You can view the proposal [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2877).